# Printing Information from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
var txt= 
{
    "people": 
    [{
        "person": 
        {
            "firstname":"Jane",
            "lastname":"Doe"
        }
    },
     {
         "person":
         {
             "firstname":"John",
             "lastname":"Smith"
         }
     }
    ]
};
```

I want the program to alert that there are two people in the list, but when I do my count function, it only says 1 (gets to 'people' then doesn't go deeper into the list).

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LipeeVora/rsBYb/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a to write a counting loop. `txt.people.length` will give you the count, as `txt.people` is an array object.

See my revised fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rsBYb/5/

---

Your loop was counting the elements in `txt` - of which there is only one (the `people` array). It would work fine if you instead use `txt.people` in the loop. You really want to count the elements in `txt.people`, not `txt`.

Example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/rsBYb/8/

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I didn't realize I could just do that haha

Comment: most languages with arrays have something like a `length` property or a built-in array `count` function. very useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
txt.people.length
```

will give you the correct answer

http://jsfiddle.net/rsBYb/6/

Answer (score 1):

It is because you count people and not persons.
Change your loop to this:

```
for ( property in txt.person )
{
    count++;
}
alert("count = " + count);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
txt.people.length
```

You might have to do a JSON.parse depending on where you're pulling your JSON string from (if you're doing anything with it outside of the fiddle)